How to stack dataframes on top of each other while retaining their column name in Pandas?
I am using Pandas to manipulate and automate my Excel report generation. So far , Ive not faced any issues with the manipulation part but while I try to make some changes to the dataframes for aesthetics , I'm running into issues.
This is how the dataframes are currently:
Dataframe1 : 

Col_Year  Col_Status
2023      Active
2022      Inactive

Dataframe2:

Col_Month  Col_SP  Col_Sales
January    Juan    2,000,234
March      Marcel  1,523,000


I want to do something like this:
Consolidated Dataframe:

Col_Year  Col_Status
2023      Active
2022      Inactive

Col_Month  Col_SP  Col_Sales
January    Juan    2,000,234
March      Marcel  1,523,000

Is there any way to do this ? I absolutely have to retain the headers for analysis purposes.

You have to loop over the dataframes to export, if you have simple indexes this is straightforward, for more complex cases you need to keep track of the number of levels
